# How do I project to remove attributes from an array that don't match a filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to filter for documents that match a filter, and then project to remove array values that don't match requirements.  In this example I need pickme1 and pickme2 to both be true.
Searching for attr $eq value

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("qewrjkl"),
  "attr" : "value",
  "aray1" [
    {
      "pickme1" : true,
      "data1" : "jklsdjk",
      "aray2" [
        {     
           "pickme2" : true,
           "data2" : "treasure1"
        },
        {     
           "pickme2" : false,
           "data2" : "trash1"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "pickme1" : false
      "data1" : "jklsdjk",
      "aray2" [
        {     
           "pickme2" : true,
           "data2" : "treasure2"
        },
        {     
           "pickme2" : false,
           "data2" : "trash2"
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

should yield

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("qewrjkl"),
  "attr" : "value",
  "results" [
    {"data2" : "treasure1"}
  ]
}
```

I started with collection.Aggregate().Match(filter).Lookup() figuring I could fill the array with the lookup, and realized that was going nowhere.
I don't have any ideas at this point.  Does anyone have any ideas?
If nothing is found inside the array then the document(s) should have an empty array.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150083/mongodb-filter-array

Comment: So if I understand that link correctly, I unwind the array, match for the item I want, and group to reassemble the array.

Comment: That is one way, yes.  Varman's awswer also shows how to do that using $map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      aray1: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$aray1",
              as: "a1",
              in: {
                aray2: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$a1.aray2",
                    as: "ia2",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$ia2.pickme2",
                        true
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                pickme1: "$$a1.pickme1",
                data1: "$$a1.data1"
              }
            }
          },
          as: "oa1",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$oa1.pickme1",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      result: "$aray1.aray2",
      attr: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "result.data2": 1,
      attr: 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IbnGO_8Ann0)**

Comment: Thanks.  I need to do this in .net using fluent, but with two examples I should be able to get it to work.