# check the condition if the values are less then or equal or greater than MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

check the conditions

1. if the `value` is greater equal 1000.
2. if the `value` is less than equal 2000.
   from the parameters, the user will select either `1` or `2`. User get the output in the same structure but only those documents that fulfill the condition in MongoDB

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 1000
        },
        {
            "value": 3000
        },
        {
            "value": 1500
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should be more clear in what the required output is.
do you want ALL items to match the conditions? do you want to just project items that match the conditions?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I want to do match the document base on the condition what user select, I have 2 parameters, the user will select `1` or `2`. If you still understand let me know , Thanks

Comment: @Taki_ I try to solve it, but I get the output as true and false. I am interested to get the values, that the user selects from the parameter. from the parameters, the user will either `1` or `2`

Comment: ok so the user selects 1 or 2, and you should send the first or the second query? You can to this in javascript and costruct like dynamic query based on 1or2, or you can do it in the database using `$cond`

Comment: I am not using javascript , only mongoDB I am using

Comment: What do you expect MongoDB to return?

Comment: @Joe when I select the parameter `1` : if the value is greater equal 1000. I get the output in the same structure but only those documents that fulfill the condition.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/63153202/2282634

Comment: check the bellow i think it does what you need,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query answers in the question :

- user enters 1 or 2 saved in a application variable lets say `var=parameter`
- if he entered 1 => i want the documents that data.value>=1000
- if he entered 2 => i want the documents that data.value<=1000

*also assumes that data(in your sample data) is an array not a collection.

Query

- make `{"eq" : [1 ,1]}` to `{"eq" : [parameter ,1]}` where parameter is your variable that has the value the user selected
- works using a condition, if the user entered 1, first comparison is made or if user entered 2 , second comparison is made
- the comparison is done with the aggregate operators, the query operators when you compare an array(the auto take the min or max), but aggregate ones doesn't do auto, so its done here with the `$max` and `$min` operators. Istead of searching for the number we find the max/min and we compare (like query operators auto-do)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ll_Ck5FbBEq)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              1,
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            "$gte": [
              {
                "$max": "$data.value"
              },
              1000
            ]
          },
          {
            "$lte": [
              {
                "$min": "$data.value"
              },
              2000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: i don't want the return true and false, I am interested to get the documents. at the moment I try it, I am getting true and false with these condition.

Comment: I want to do the aggregation, and match the conditions. and yes `data` is an array of objects, I want to do check the condition on `value` object

Comment: Thanks to its works, do you have an idea? If I have an operator as a parameter and value that passes from the parameter that checks the condition on the dataset. for example, I pass the parameter operator as `$gte` and `value` as 1000, so then it is more flexible.

Comment: you can do the same in the driver, and make smaller query, youo can generate the query dynamically. You can also use parameter for the opertors, MQL queries can be dynamic made from the apprlication.

Comment: youo is the tool name ? can you paste the link ? which tool you are talking about for mongo db

Comment: youo=you , its not a tool, i just mean that you can construct those JSON code, using your programming language, instead of writting by hand, to allow dynamic behaviour, Like auto-construct queries

Comment: I have to do in the query, now I have the same structure, but I want to check if the condition is satisfied then 1, else 0 in the same structure, we can introduce the new field., also example want to check value is > 500 but < 1000.  these values come from the parameter also operator come from the parameter.
do you have idea how we can do ?

Comment: i think its best to write a new question adding the extra things. Yes `$addFileds` can do this, also the array can be filtered. if you want make a new query explaining what you want, and give sample data.